# Как повторить ввод с клавиатуры, при исключении

Tags: java

Подскажите как, повторять ввод строки, если ее нельзя преобразовать в тип int или double...

```
String j = inc.readLine(); // ввели строку
     // пробуем преобразовать в тип double
    double resl = Double.parseDouble(j); 
 // если преобразование невозможно, повторить ввод заново
  ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Double parsing() {
    String j = inc.readLine(); // ввели строку
    Double resl;
    try {
        resl = Double.parseDouble(j);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return parsing();
    }
    return resl;
}
```

Логика такая: пробуете (`try`) спарсить значение, если не получилось, ловите (`catch`) исключение (`Exception e`), и рекурсивно вызываете эту же функцию.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.

Comment: Я бы поостерегся здесь рекурсию использовать - если юзер упорный, можно и стек исчерпать :) Я бы сделал как-то так:   `while (true) {
  try {
    j = inc.readLine(); // ввели строку
    return(Double.parseDouble(j));
  } catch (Exception x) {
    System.out.print("appropriate message here");
  }
}
`